# How to make a web app using both django and express? How would you interchange data between the two platforms?

Tags: django, express

I was trying to make a web app with a complicated idea and at some point realised that I couldn't do it alone. When, I started to look around for friends with a skill set with node in their bag, I found out that everyone had experience with pure php or django. I was thinking if I could make the web app by combining different backend technologies. But I can't really understand where and how to start. What would I need to learn? How would I exchange values or data between the two frameworks or programming languages? What things would I have to learn? Where would I start?

Answer (score 0):

REST API, you can use it to exchange data easly